# Understanding Memory Leak from Material UI Table and Modal - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, react-hooks

I've got two files in my React app where I believe there is a memory leak occurring in one of them. Essentially, one of the files is a `MaterialTable` and the other is a modal using `Dialog`, both of which are Material UI Core components.

In my `MaterialTable`, I've basically got a button that opens up the modal with more information than that which is displayed in the table. As a summary of my code, these are the two files in question:

**myTable.js**

```
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)

const myTable = () => {
  return (
    <div>

    <MyModal
      isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
      setIsModalOpen={setIsModalOpen}
    />

    <MaterialTable
      data={/*my data goes here*/}
      actions={[
        {
          icon: "edit",
          tooltip: "More information",
          onClick: (_event, rowData) => {
            /* open modal */
            setIsModalOpen(true)
          }
        }
      ]}

    </div>
  )
}
```

The subsequent modal file looks something like this:

**myModal.js**

```
const MyModal = (isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen) => {
  return (
    <Dialog open={isModalOpen} maxWidth={"md"} fullWidth={true}
      /* display some stuff in the modal view
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

When I open and close the modal several times from within `myTable.js`, I get a memory leak. After investigating the memory from within the DevTools, I can see the following (apologies for the bad resolution):

[image]

[image]

Both of the objects/strings seem to be coming from Material UI. In one of the objects example, I can see that it may be coming from `node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Slider/Slider.js`. I'm not really sure what I need to do in order to resolve this issue.

To clarify, I don't have the `calc(...)` string in any part of my code and therefore I believe it's being originated from one of the Material UI components.

Where can I start to identify the issue and/or how can I go by resolving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the fact that I was defining the `options` and `columns` for `Material-Table` in a different file. It turns out that this may be a known issue as seen here: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2650

As a result, declaring `options` and `columns` in the same component where the table is being defined resolved the memory leak issue.